# subtraction operation on multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list.

```
l = [[1, 2, 8] [8, 2, 7] [7, 2, 5]]
```

I want first element to be zero and then I need to subtract values columnwise.
explanation :

```
1 2 8
8 2 7
7 2 5
```

subtraction as,

```
0 1 6
0 -6 5
0 -5 3
```

I want output as :

```
l = [[0, 1, 6], [0, -6, 5], [0, -5, 3]]
```

which is the faster way to perform this operation if I have large list?

I am using numpy but I changed here so that easy to understand
my numpy array object is

```
l = [[1  2  8] [8  2  7] [7  2  5]]
```

Comment: Are you using `numpy`?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `numpy`?

Comment: I am using numpy but I changed here so that easy to understand. In actual operation I am using numpy

Comment: The easiest way to do something like that would be to map a reduce function to each line. No numpy necessary.

Comment: Loic; easiest is disputable, although the numpy solution is more compact. But certainly, the numpy solution is going to be a lot faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy.insert` and `numpy.diff`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 8], [8, 2, 7], [7, 2, 5]])
>>> np.insert(np.diff(a), 0, 0, axis=1)
array([[ 0,  1,  6],
       [ 0, -6,  5],
       [ 0, -5,  3]])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> l = np.array([[1, 2, 8], [8, 2, 7], [7, 2, 5]])
>>> l[:, 1:] -= l[:, :-1]
>>> l[:, 0] = 0
>>> l
array([[ 0,  1,  6],
       [ 0, -6,  5],
       [ 0, -5,  3]])
```

Comment: Why the negative strides? `l[:, 1:] -= l[:, :-1]` seems to work just the same, am I missing something?

Comment: @Jaime, You're right. I didn't need to use negative strides. I updated the answer to use simpler one. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 1):

Without numpy, you can get away with this

```
l = [[1,  2,  8], [8,  2,  7], [7,  2,  5]]

def minus(rest, val):
    rest[-1] -= val
    rest.append(val)
    return rest

def myReduce(l):
    l2 = reduce(minus, l[-2::-1], [l[-1]])
    l2.reverse()
    l2[0] = 0
    return l2

l2 = map(myReduce, l)

print l2
```

I guess it's quite straightforward and easy to understand.